# How does this syntax for main work?

Tags: c

OK, let me preface this with the fact that I'm trying to understand one of the winning entries in the 2013 [International Obfuscated C Code Contest](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Obfuscated_C_Code_Contest).

[Here](http://www.ioccc.org/2013/dlowe/dlowe.c)'s the entry.  I doubt I'll ever fully understand it, but something caught my eye that didn't seem to make any sense at all right off the bat.  Look at the function declaration for `main`:

```
main (a,b) char**b;
{...}
```

How would this even compile?  I get that some compilers will probably infer the `int` return type for `main`, and I know that `main` can take two parameters for the command-line args, but the parameters set up (`a` and `b`) don't have types either, and what's the deal with the random `char**b` between the parentheses and brackets?

I'm so confused, but I guess that's the point...

Comment: I marked this as a dupe of another question about K&R syntax; if that's not enough let me know.

Comment: Thanks! Sorry for the dupe. I didn't even know what to Google :P

Comment: The inferred return type for main would be int, not void-